# CSS Greyscale Masking

Tags: css, mask

I am wondering if it would be possible to partially mask an object in CSS with greyscale. I could do this with images, although it would be quite difficult to make an image for 10% greyscale, 11% greyscale, etc.

default left, right 90% greyscale:

[image: Default]

An example of what I'm looking to do (This would represent 50% greyscale mask):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to apply a filter to part of an image, but my usual way of accomplishing something like this is to simply duplicate the image, apply the filter to all of one of the images, and then only show the portion of each image that I want to:

```css
#container {
  width:250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#right, #left {
  max-width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  float:right
}

#right img {
 position: relative;
 left: -100%;
}
#left {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="right">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/08h6Q.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/08h6Q.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can do the same thing with objects, just put them in containers, make the width of each container whatever part you want to show, hide the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Make background of two divs, left and right, and for the left div set:

background-color: gray;
background-blend-mode: multiply;